# how template inheritance works?

Tags: c++

```
template<typename T>
class A {
public:
    A(const T &t )
    {
        std::cout << t;
    }
};
class C :
    public A<int>,
    public A<char>
{

public:
    C(char c) : A<char>(c) {}

};

void main()
{
    C obj('c');

}
```

While compiling following program, compiler is giving following error.
no default constructor exists for class "A<int>"

what compiler does internally?

Comment: Who cares what the compiler does internally. You haven't provided an initializer for one of your base subobjects, that's all that matters.

Comment: Why do you construct the `A<char>` part of `C` but not the `A<int>`?

Comment: Compiler is telling you exactly  what the problem is.

Comment: @Kerrek SB,, why do I need a default constructor. From where I am invoking default constructor of A<char>? can you please explain?

Comment: @user966379 You're also inheriting from `A<int>`, which is what the error message is messaging you about.

Comment: @user966379: It's the same as `struct A : B, C`: every constructor of `A` must construct the `B` and `C` subobjects. If you don't provide an initializer, a default constructor must be available.

Comment: Templates don't inherit. Classes do. Class templates are patterns for creating classes. So when you have problems with inheritance, think about classes, not templates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`C` has two base classes - `A<int>` and `A<char>`. You have specified the explicit call to the base class `A<char>` constructor but you have not specified anything for the base class `A<int>`. When a constructor is not explicitly used in the initializer-list, the compiler tries to call the default constructor. Hence,

```
C(char c) : A<char>(c) {}
```

is equivalent to:

```
C(char c) : A<char>(c), A<int>() {}
```

That is a problem since `A` does not define a default constructor. You can use

```
C(char c) : A<char>(c), A<int>(0) {}
```

to resolve the problem.

Comment: A is an object with Plain Old Data (POD).   Why doesn't the compiler supply a default ctor?

Comment: @Gregg, The default constructor is removed by the compiler when another user defined constructor is defined. That's how the language is defined.